# Strange dispose behavior while testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, testing

I Have endpoint which use handlers of 2 others endpoints it's probably not best practice, but it's not the point. In this methods I use a lot of MemoryStreams, ZipStream and stuff like that. Of course I dispose all of them. And everything works good till I run all tests together, then tests throw errors like: “Input string was not in a correct format.”, "Cannot read Zip file" or other weird messages. This are also test of this 2 handlers which I use in previous test.
Solution what I found is to add "Thread.Sleep(1);" at the end of the "Handle" method, just before return. It looks like something need more time to dispose, but why?. Have you any ideas why this 1ms sleep help with this?

`ExtractFilesFromZipAndWriteToGivenZipArchive` is an async method.

```
public async Task<MemoryStream> Handle(MultipleTypesExportQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var stepwiseData = await HandleStepwise(request.RainmeterId, request.StepwiseQueries, cancellationToken); 
        var periodicData = await HandlePeriodic(request.RainmeterId, request.PeriodicQueries, cancellationToken);
        
        var data = new List<MemoryStream>();
        data.AddRange(stepwiseData);
        data.AddRange(periodicData);

        await using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create,false))
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var d in data)
            {
                d.Open();
                d.Position = 0;
                
                var file = ZipFile.Read(d);
                
                ExtractFilesFromZipAndWriteToGivenZipArchive(file, archive, i, cancellationToken);
                
                i++;
                file.Dispose();
                d.Dispose();
            }
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            return ms;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is ExtractFilesFromZipAndWriteToGivenZipArchive() async?

Comment: Post the actual full exceptions. Use a `using` block to ensure streams are properly disposed. There's nothing related to CQRS in this code. The errors may occur in the code you didn't post. `Input string was not in a correct format.` is thrown when you try to parse a string using the wrong format or locale. The code you posted doesn't parse strings, so one of the other methods failed

Comment: If problems stop by adding a delay it means that *your code* isn't thread safe and is suffering from race conditions. The full exception (the string returned by Exception.ToString()) and the *actual* code are necessary

Comment: Yes, ExtractFilesFromZipAndWriteToGivenZipArchive() was not async!, when I added "await" everything works properly. If you want to write answer @T.Trassoudaine I will accept with glad ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtractFilesFromZipAndWriteToGivenZipArchive() is an asynchronous function which means, in this case, that you need to `await` it:

```
await ExtractFilesFromZipAndWriteToGivenZipArchive(file, archive, i, cancellationToken);
```

Otherwise, the execution will keep going without waiting the function to return.